AdonisJS - Lucid idempotent-methods - `updateOrCreateMany()` issue
I need to understand a 500 error on a single attribute in DB when doing an updateOrCreateMany() that I don't get when doing an updateOrCreate().
Here is my code for the updateOrCreateMany():
const payload = [
  {
    githubId: anotherId,
    name: myName,
    status: myStatus,
  },
  ...
]
// Here, githubId is a unique string in DB
await MyTable.updateOrCreateMany('githubId', payload)

This code gives me the following error:
--> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_github_id_unique"
It seems to me that updateOrCreateMany() should handle this on its own.
Everything works correctly using updateOrCreate() but the code is less maintainable:
const payload = [
  {
    githubId: anotherId,
    name: myName,
    status: myStatus,
  },
  ...
]

payload.forEach(async (item: any) => {
  const searchPayload = { githubId: item.githubId }
  await MyTable.updateOrCreate(searchPayload, item)
})

--> works like a charm but makes a lot more requests to the DB:
I followed the Lucid doc for the idempotent-methods: https://lucid.adonisjs.com/docs/crud-operations#idempotent-methods
I'd love your help 
Thank you very much

I suggest that you insert the for loop inside a transaction, so you have just one connection with the database, for better performance.
const Database = use('Database');

await Database.transaction(async (trx) => {
  for (const item of payload) {
    const searchPayload = { githubId: item.githubId };
    await MyTable.updateOrCreate(searchPayload, item, { client: trx });
  }
});


I see your point to improve performance. I did the following in a transaction
await db.transaction(async (trx): Promise<void> => {
    for (const item of payload) {
      const searchPayload = { githubId: item.githubId }
      await WorkflowRun.updateOrCreate(searchPayload, item, { client: trx })
    }
 })

But that does not explain why updateOrCreateMany() does not work

@fralps, this needs debugging on your end, but it could be for race conditions because of concurrent operations or data conflicts.
